# How to redirect the selected option to a header

Tags: php, html

I have a drop down menu,with multiple options.How do i redirect the user to different pages depending on selected option?

//the php code is as follows

```
  <?php
        session_start();
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            if($_POST['options'] == "" ){
                header("Location: error.html");
                exit; 
            }else{
                $checked = $_POST['options'];
                $_SESSION['checked'] = $checked;
            }
        }
        ?>
```

the user is already logged in,i just need to redirect the user to the selected option header.

Comment: ans is already in your que...add redirect code in else condition

Comment: _i just need to redirect the user to the selected option header._ What does that actually mean

Comment: in option use urls for value the header("Location:" .$_POST['options']); like:
$_POST['options']="mytest.php";
header("Location:". $_POST['options']); in else part.

Comment: Do you mean `header("Location: $checked");`

Comment: This question is unclear. If you posted and left only to return at a future date, then you will need to wait for other people to see the rest of your code, being the HTML form. In the meantime, check for errors; you may be outputting before header. People have asked for clarification; you should respond. I being part of the present audience have left the question.

Comment: i need to redirect the user to a new page based on the option selected

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect user on the error page if user does not select any thing then try following code, Note that you have to define full url in header location.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if(isset($_POST['options'])) {
            $checked = $_POST['options'];
            $_SESSION['checked'] = $checked;
        } else {
            header("Location: https://www.example.com/error.html");
            exit; 
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: How does this improve on the code in the question? It doesn't redirect to anywhere new.